# How to make a search bar in cake php?

Tags: web, cakephp-3.0, searchbar

I want a search bar that will search each time the user enters or deletes a character. The research is done in two columns with an 'OR'.

(EDITED)

I've been able to make my search bar with ajax comunication. But once the user has the search results, the use of the paginator cause an Method Not Allowed on this line of my search function of the controller :

$this->request->allowMethod('ajax');

Comment: You should use some JavaScript and Ajax. There are plugins that do this for you, and loads of tutorials out there to help. The JavaScript part of it doesn't need to know anything about Cake, it just communicates via Ajax to your Cake controller. When you've tried some things and run into a specific problem, post those details here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on writing a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide much description in the question, as per the description what you need is the autocomplete functionality.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ This is the JQ based autocomplete plugin, helped me in a number of project for searching DB when a user enters something in the search box